# Signing a xml file with a certificate with quotes

Tags: c#, digital-signature, xml-signature

I'm signing a XML-file using SignedXml (C#).
In my certificate, the name of the organization is quoted. For example: "BANK NAME".
As a result, the following code:

```
KeyInfoX509Data kiData = new KeyInfoX509Data (certificate);
kiData.AddSubjectName (certificate.Subject);
KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo ();
keyInfo.AddClause (kiData);
```

Generates an XML element in which the quotes are repeated 3 times:

```
<KeyInfo>
   <X509Data>
      <X509SubjectName> CN = bank.com, OU = IT Department, O = """BANK NAME""", L=City</X509SubjectName>
   </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

Please tell me this is normal behavior or quotes should be somehow escaped?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry too much if the signed XML can be parsed and the signature can be verified correctly.

Comment: It certainly doesn't feel right; I've seen many ways of escaping double quotes, but this is not one of them.